# Fetch database according to multi-dimensional php session array for a quiz software

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

[check database structure image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgwvw.png) I am creating a computer-based test /quiz, this is how it works,
  When the user selects a question and select on the answer the question and the selected answer is saved in a multi-dimensional php session array.

```
Array
(
     [1] => Array
     (
         [something] => 1
         [culture] => 1
     )

     [2] => Array
     (
         [Solving problem] => 1
     )

     [4] => Array
     (
         [Adonai] => 1
     )

 )
```

the checked answers are *question 1: something, culture
question 2: solving problem
question 3: Adonai*

The problem here is that I want to save the user answers which is a multi-dimensional array into the database. Here is my code to print the answer according to the database before storing the answer into the database,

```
 case "submit";
    $sql1 = "Select * from questions ";
        $query_count=$conn->query($sql1);
        $res =$conn->query($sql1);
        $quest = array();
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $quest[$row['q_num']] = $row;
            $quest[$row['OPTION_A']] = $row;
            $quest[$row['OPTION_B']] = $row;
            $quest[$row['OPTION_C']] = $row;
            $quest[$row['OPTION_D']] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($_SESSION['option'] as $id => $num) {
            echo '<br/>';
            printf(
                $id,
                $num,
                $quest[$id]['OPTION_C'],
                $num['OPTION_C']
            );

            // echo     $quest[$id]['OPTION_B'];
            // echo     $quest[$id]['OPTION_C'];
            // echo     $quest[$id]['OPTION_D'];
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        //fetching the last sub data in php session

        break;

 }

?>
```

how do I fetch the answer selected from PHP session per question into the database?

Comment: Do you have any table for the answer? where do you want to store the answers?

Comment: check the image attached@dWinder

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you please elaborate on what is the input and what you want to achieve?

Comment: How do i fetch the second array in the multi dimensional array into database @dWinder

Comment: The array is the user answer - to which table you want to insert it? in the image you share only the question table and not the useranswers... How can you tell the user id?  I would start with loop on the array and execute sql INSERT for each element

Comment: Create your a table and solve the problem if you can thanks